# Нужна помощь! Есть словарь и нужно его отфильтровать!

Tags: python

Дан словарь:

```
ids = {'user1': [213, 213, 213, 15, 213],
       'user2': [54, 54, 119, 119, 119],
       'user3': [213, 98, 98, 35]}
```

Как можно его отфильтровать, что бы получился список с совподающими элементами данного словаря?

Comment: В этом словаре нет совпадений. Ни ключи не совпадают, ни их значения. Чего вы хотите-то? Убрать дубли в списках? Или оставить только дубли? Или получить список чисел которые содержатся в более чем одном списке? Не понятно.

Comment: не понятен вопрос, можете изложить по другому

Comment: Убрать дубли и вывести уникальные значения в новый список

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Так "что бы получился список с совподающими элементами" или "Убрать дубли и вывести уникальные значения в новый список"? Это же две противоположные задачи вообще. Сформулируйте нормально и приведите пример: дано - то-то, на выходе должно получиться - то-то.

Comment: Есть список! Нужно убрать из него дубли и вывести уникальные значения(цифры) в отдельный list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например можно попробовать так если правильно понял Вашу мысль.

```py
ids = {'user1': [213, 213, 213, 15, 213],
       'user2': [54, 54, 119, 119, 119],
       'user3': [213, 98, 98, 35]}
new_ids = {}
for k, v in ids.items():       
       new_ids[k] = set(v)

print(new_ids)
# {'user1': {213, 15}, 'user2': {54, 119}, 'user3': {98, 35, 213}}


# Или если нужен только список уникальных чисел ВСЕГО словаря
new_list = []
for _, v in ids.items():
       for i in v:
              new_list.append(i)
print(set(new_list))
# {98, 35, 15, 213, 54, 119}
```

Comment: Cпасибо Вам огромное! А не подскажите как тоже самое сделать через множество?

Comment: @СашаПрохоренко так `set(v)` и есть множество. Вы получаете только уникальные значение для каждого значения словаря